How does one demodulate a signal correctly in python using komm.dev library?
Im not sure if I need to downsample or filter but as of now this code has a 45% bit error rate and I need to understand how to correctly demodulate something like this coming off an SDR.
Thanks!
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal as sig
import komm

bpsk_modem = komm.PSKModulation(2)


# create BPSK signal
# Generate random bit stream
bits = np.random.randint(0, 2, 256)

baseband = bpsk_modem.modulate(bits)

# zero insert upsample (10 samples per symbol)
rate = 10
baseband_upsampled = np.zeros(len(baseband) * rate, dtype='complex')
baseband_upsampled[::rate] = baseband

# pulse shaping filter (root raised cosine filter)
pulse = komm.RootRaisedCosinePulse(rolloff=0.25, length_in_symbols=16)
n = np.linspace(-8, 8, 16 * rate)
psf_coeff = pulse.impulse_response(n)
baseband_shaped = sig.lfilter(psf_coeff, np.sum(psf_coeff), baseband_upsampled)

# welch psd at baseband
faxis, psd_baseband = sig.welch(baseband_shaped, nperseg=2**12, return_onesided=False)
plot_psd(faxis, psd_baseband, "baseband")


downsamp = sig.resample(baseband_shaped, 256)
demodulated_bits = bpsk_modem.demodulate(downsamp)

print(baseband.shape, demodulated_bits.shape)

ber = np.sum(bits != demodulated_bits) / len(bits)
print(f'Bit Error Rate (BER): {ber}')
```


Hi Max- It's unlikely that someone will dive into this level of debugging here so I'm voting to close this question as being much too broad. Demodulating an SDR waveform is much more involved as it also includes the proper implementation of carrier recovery and timing recovery. I linked my upcoming "DSP for Software Radio" course in your other posts and recommend that if you really want to dive into knowing how to do this! This site isn't really set up for full tutorial / courses that would really address a question like this.

You can also search here for "Carrier Recovery" and "Timing Recovery" as there are several existing posts that go into further details of that which should help provide further insight into what I am getting at. There is also AGC which we could call "gain recovery" (but no-one does).
